# MySQL "You have an error in your SQL syntax" error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 10

What is my error and what is the solution?

```
CREATE TABLE login(
user_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
password VARCHAR(10) NOT 'NULL DEFAULT",
email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
account_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
ic INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
telephone_no INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
pin INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
gender VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
shipping_address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
city VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL DEFAULT",
state VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
country VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
zip_code INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
credit_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
credit_number INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
cvv2 INT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT",
);
```

Comment: Were the " introduced when copying SQL to this question?

Comment: ASAP=as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL developer here (so not sure how much I can help you with your toy RDBMS) but from reading the error message you have an extra `,` before `);`.

Further, it seems that you've got an extra `'` on the third line, and the syntax you're using for `DEFAULT` doesn't make sense (let alone the empty strings you're setting for `INT` columns).

Perhaps:

```
CREATE TABLE login
  (
     user_name        VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     password         VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     email            VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     account_type     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     ic               INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
     telephone_no     INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
     pin              INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
     gender           VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     shipping_address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     city             VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     state            VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     country          VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     zip_code         INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
     credit_type      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     credit_number    INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
     cvv2             INT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  );
```

Personally I am concerned that someone asking this question has a field called `credit_number` and a `password` field that's not matched by a `salt` field, nor is `password` long enough for a SHA1 hash.

Comment: Not to mention all kinds of random single-quotes sprinkled throughout.

Comment: @dbaseman I'm having trouble parsing `"` as `''`. I think that's what he intended. That is, the default value is an empty string.

Comment: Not to mention that the field cvv2 (abbreviation which is specific to Visa) is forbidden by Visa from being stored once the individual transaction is authorized and completed. Cant store amex since its card identification number is 4 digits (not 3).

Comment: A downvote for "toy RDBMS" - not ideal to try starting a platform war!

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax is:

```
CREATE TABLE login (
    user_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    password VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    account_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ic INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    telephone_no INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    pin INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    gender VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    shipping_address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    city VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    state VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    country VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    zip_code INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    credit_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    credit_number INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    cvv2 INT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

I have just corrected the syntax from your create syntax, you should download some tool like [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) (or [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net), so that you don't need to struggle to generate correct DML syntax) and make sure that what defaults you're looking for because I am sure you don't need 0 as default for all Integer fields and '' (empty string) as default for all varchar or char fields.

You're the best decision maker for your table design and I am sure you might not want all fields as NOT NULL and some of them can have NULL value too. Now when you allow NULL value, you don't need DEFAULT to be specified for that field.